# What are UserEngagement, MicroblogUsageTelemetry, RequestUsage and FeatureUsage logs and how to stop them

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2016, logs

My SharePoint 2016 is generating a lot of these logs. From where are they coming and how to stop them. SP log level is set to default.

```
UserEngagement
MicroblogUsageTelemetry
RequestUsage
FeatureUsage
```

Answer (score 0):

See: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/254386d0-f372-462a-85d0-94fc6d03a802/turning-off-featureused-logging
And: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/view-data-in-the-logging-database

Go to Central Administration >> Monitoring >> Reporting >> Configure diagnostic logging and customize the settings there.

If you want to disable a specific log like FeatureUsage, you can do so under "configure usage and health data collection" in Monitoring in Central Administration